# javascript drop down menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Really love the drop down that I found on http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/04/sliding-javascript-dropdown-menu/

I have 4 Menus and when I add this this flows over the logo. The size of each menu is in fact too big. When I tried to alter this the size of sub-menus stay the same and it was looking ugly. I can't attach screenshot as SO doesnt allow me to.
I basically want the size of the menu box to be smaller;
CSS code is :

```
body {margin-left:140px; font:12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica}
* {padding:0; margin:0}
.dropdown {float:right; padding-right:5px}
.dropdown dt {width:188px; border:2px solid #9ac1c9; padding:8px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; background:url(images/header.gif)}
.dropdown dt:hover {background:url(images/header_over.gif)}
.dropdown dd {position:absolute; overflow:hidden; width:208px; display:none; background:#fff; z-index:200; opacity:0}
.dropdown ul {width:204px; border:2px solid #9ac1c9; list-style:none; border-top:none}
.dropdown li {display:inline}
.dropdown a, .dropdown a:active, .dropdown a:visited {display:block; padding:5px; color:#333; text-decoration:none; background:#eaf0f2; width:194px}
.dropdown a:hover {background:#d9e1e4; color:#000}
.dropdown .underline {border-bottom:1px solid #b9d6dc}
```

Comment: Is this a question? It is unlikely that you will get anyone to answer this in its current form, putting the code that you have and then asking why you are getting the behaviour would be a better approach.

Comment: If you had linked to the actual site you're using this on (or at least showed a little code), it would have made a huge difference and people would take you more seriously.

Comment: ...or even a screenshot. Or an explanation of what "not aligned properly" means.

Comment: Sorry, first time on SO.
I'll add a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't figure it out the way it is, put it in a div with `float:right`

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <!-- Your navigation markup -->
</div>

.nav-wrapper {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Glenn. Can we have more detail of what you did/tried?

I tested with FireFox 4.01 and FireFox 5.0 with a float:right on the dropdown class and got the results I expected.

EDIT:

++ to Wesley's solution as it's cleaner to wrap outside the dropwdown class...

[image: Result]

Comment: Yeah this worked fine for me too. I honestly didn't even look at the demo. Maybe he's talking about a flyout menu and the 3rd level links are going off screen to the right. We'll probably never know... +1 for taking a look even though the question was weak.